# how can i change a global var in window.onscroll event?

Tags: javascript

```js
var flag=false;

window.onscroll=function(){ 

  if(document.querySelector('html').scrollTop >300){

    flag=true;

    } //this condition is just a example
}

//flag will be true only in onscroll event
```

Comment: Make sure the user CAN actually scroll on the page:)

Comment: Just tried this, your code works perfectly fine

Comment: It should work fine, but don't forget to throttle the callback as it will run way too many times :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the user can actually scroll the page.
Start by making the body have a style of more than the view height of the page

```js
var flag = false;

window.onscroll = function() {

  if (document.querySelector('html').scrollTop > 300) {

    flag = true;
    alert(flag)

  } //this condition is just a example
}

//flag will be true only in onscroll event
```

```html
<body style="overflow: scroll;min-height: 1000px;"></body>
```